# PHP - Best way to extract associative POST data

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I have this $_POST array thing:

```
  'name' => string '' (length=0)
  'limit' => string '100' (length=3)

  'timeframe' => 
    array
      'start' => string '00:00' (length=5)
      'end' => string '23:30' (length=5)

  'person' => 
    array
      'test' => string '' (length=0)
      'title' => 
        array
          0 => string 'value1' (length=2)
          1 => string 'value2' (length=3)
```

I want to extract data for a field named `person[title][]`, what is the best way to do this efficiently?

Actually I narrowed down the problem to this example, but am implementing this more generally so I can extract data for any array-named field in my code.

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, I think I was unclear, here's the problem again:

I have a field name in this format: `name_1[name_2]..[name_n][]` and the its value is available in `$_POST` associative array, I need extract that value (which is an array because of that [] at the end).

I can just extract sub-names from the original fieldname by running a `preg_match` or somethin', and then loop through the array till I find the value using extracted indexes. But I'm not sure if it's really the best and/or efficient way of doing this.

Sorry for being unclear at the first place ^^

---

**UPDATE 2**

Guys, I said that I narrowed down the problem to this example, but there's no `person` thing in my real application. I'm developing a data parser engine to struggle with huge arrays of data and that feature is just what it needs. Hope it;'s clear now.

Thank you all, btw ^^

Comment: $_POST['person']['title'] would give you the array, but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking

Comment: could you please share results of `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` because it's a bit unclear.

Comment: @metal_fan: That's actually the result of `var_dump($_POST)` with xdebug in place. Here's the path: `$_POST['person']['title']` which is an array.

Comment: @artarad so the depth of the array is not always the same or what?

Comment: @artarad have you thought about treating it like a path? E.g. person/bla/yadda/title, then explode() on slash and iterate over each level of your big array

Comment: @Jack, Nice! But unfortunately the user provides it like form fieldnames. I should exract the array indexes anyway.

Comment: @artarad, if that's the only problem: explode('][', rtrim($path, ']'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here you go:

```
/**
 * Extracts value from an associative array by fieldname sequence.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * This string:
 * my_group[my_subgroup][multiselect_field][]
 *
 * Requests the helper to extract the value of: (if exists)
 * $array[my_group][my_subgroup][multiselect_field]
 *
 * @param  string $name  Fieldname string.
 * @param  array  $array Haystack array to dig.
 *
 * @return array  Extracted value or FALSE on failure.
 */
function _extract_value($name, array $array)
{
    // Check if it's a array fieldname, go for brackets
    if (strpos($name, '[') !== FALSE AND preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/', $name, $matches))
    {
        $count  = count($matches[0]);
        $keys[] = current(explode('[', $name));

        // Extract fieldname keys
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        {
            $matches[1][$i] != '' AND $keys[] = $matches[1][$i];
        }

        return _reduce($array, $keys);
    }

    return FALSE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Helper: Reduces the array by the passed array of keys which leds to find the value!
 *
 * Traverses a multi-dimensional array until the value of the keys specified
 * in keys array is found. Returns FALSE if not found.
 *
 * @param  array   $array Array to reduce.
 * @param  array   $keys  Array keys sequence. Traverse map in fact.
 * @param  integer $i     $keys array index to start from.
 *
 * @return array          Extracted value or FALSE on failure.
 */
function _reduce($array, $keys, $i = 0)
{
    // Not an array, or a wrong index to start
    if ( ! is_array($array) OR ! isset($keys[$i]))
    {
        return $array;
    }

    // Go deep, find the value
    return isset($array[$keys[$i]])
        ? _reduce($array[$keys[$i]], $keys, $i + 1)
        : FALSE;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------

$titles = _extract_value('', $_POST);
var_dump($titles);
```

*Taken from CodeIgniter's `Form_validation` library.*

Comment: well, finally!! i'll test and report back ^^

Comment: yes!! im sorry for late reply, i just forgot about it ^^ thank you again

Answer (score 3):

I would use `$title = $_POST['perosn']['title']`.

Or even better take whole person and convert it to object.

```
$person = (object)$_POST['person'];
echo $person->name // Call it
```

Comment: why you say that is it better to cast into object? Does it make sense?

Comment: According to the structure presented in the question, how one can get the contents of 'title' in the person object? Does $person->title->0 works?

Comment: Well, the casting isn't required here. It's just matter of preference.

Comment: True, it's my preference to use Objects rather than Arrays. I just thought I share this preference with everyone, guess not :)

Comment: To access a title in this form it would be `$person->title[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

To be VERY specific to the question:

> I want to extract data for a field named person[title][], what is the
>   best way to do this efficiently?

Well, `<? $person[title][]?>` --- we cant use  that for reading.
If you try to read the way you do, PHP will produce fatal error.
We use `[]` to push new elements to the given array.
Again - only add new items.
In order to read the ones, you'd only access only desired `key` of the array.

In your case, you'd access `$_POST['person']['title']`

You're asking about the best way to do it, but it all depends on the task you're dealing with.

Well, if we are talking about `$_POST` then probably we are dealing with a form. In order to keep your code clean and maintainable you should really use deeper arrays like you have.

Why?

You'd have `<input type="text" name="name_of_the_current[]">`(look we are defining an array) No need to make it deeper.

**UPDATE**

Hey, we are dealing with simple form. Why $_POST is too deep? Well, It's not a good idea anyway, because of the reasons:

1) It makes a bit harder to maintain your exiting `HTML/PHP` code. Just imagine if you have to update / modify something in your code. I guess it's gonna take some time.

2) `Deep array` also means a bit more time to iterate over it. (about ~0.0008 ms (in your case), correct me if I am wrong)

I'm so sorry, but I have to suggest you something what is more appropriate :)

1) First, the person is `PRIMARY AND UNIQUE KEY`, right? I guess it is.

For example,
Most php developers usually do like this:

```
<?php
//suppose we have it from database or from
$persons = array
(
  'john_123' => array('age' = 40, 'gender' =>'M', 'location' => 'somewhere'),
  'linde_22' => array('age' = 30, 'gender' =>'F', 'location' => 'somewhere_else')  
);

//
print $persons['john_123']['age']; //prints 40...
?>
```

**Benefits**:

1. It's clean
2. Easy to maintain
3. Not too deep
4. A bit faster

Comment: I updated the question, metal_fan. Would you please have a look? ty

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I know what you're saying but that's not ma point I just set that `person` name for example purpose. I'm developing a data parser engine which requires such feature (as I said in my update) in general. ty anyway :D

Comment: @artarad Honestly I couldn't fully get into your problem, but tried to. Well, then use `<?php foreach ($_POST as $index => $array){  if (is_array($array)){ /* Do deep iteration right here and don't forget to break the loop */  } }`

Comment: Thank you for your time, really. You know, I'm looking for a more general way of facing this huge arrays. I'll update the question with more details. ty, ty ^^

Comment: @artarad Listen up, When we develop data engine parser, we always focuse on, and I'm talking about "MORE GENERAL WAY", 1) Kind of the data (i.e data analyzer like validate functions and so on... 2) Maximal allowed depth of the arrays 3) Data verifier and extractor (both are custom functions or methods in some class) 4) Data collector (that is some array with successful ones). This is the way to go, at least I think. because I did something like this one (data with deep array parser) and it worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Pre-optimization is the devil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) - Until you're really at a place where you're encountering that this piece of code causes the bottleneck in your software development efforts, you should really avoid any optimization, it'll be more likely that your bottlenecks will be in the DB, way before you'll notice a drop in speed.

First - make it work.
Second - improve it.

From the array you've provided, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($arr['person']['title'] as $title){
  if ($title == $match_condition) // do something
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying Itai, but I'm developing a data parser engine which requires such feature (as I said in my update) in general. That's just its purpose, not the bottleneck :p